# How to implement scss in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement SCSS in my project. I have ran the npm command to install the loader "npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev". I have created a scss file. but the problem is it is not working. i tried multiple configurations to make it runable but no luck. below are my webpack configuration. please advice,

```
rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                cacheDirectory: true
            }
        }]
```

Comment: What kind of an error are you getting?

Comment: @KornholioBeavis If i am using above configuration then scss not apply. if i am using below config. 

rules: [{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'],
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                options: {
                    cacheDirectory: true
                }
            }]

getting below error:---

Error: options/query cannot be used with loaders (use options for each array item) in {
  "test": {},
  "loaders": [
    "style",

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure your loaders correctly? Cant at least see any css/scss loaders in your provided code? https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader

UPDATE::

Add ExtractTextPlugin into your config. What this does is, it moves all the require("style.css")s in entry chunks into a separate single CSS file. So your styles are no longer inlined into the JS bundle, but separate in a CSS bundle file (styles.css) https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin

Include the following into your webpack.config file.

```
// webpack.config.js
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin'

 {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallbackLoader: 'style',
      loader: [
        'css',
        'postcss',
        {
          loader: 'sass',
          query: {
            sourceMap: false,
          }
        }
      ],
    })
  }
```

and import your .scss files ::

```
import 'scss/myfile.scss'
```

Comment: tried the above code but getting "Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: \index.js Unexpected token (8:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

Comment: Have you installed all the above loaders? npm install -S style-loader css-loader sass-loader

Comment: Have you checked index.js Line 8?

Comment: @KornholioBeavis yes, i have installed the loaders and it is present in package.json

Comment: @dschu at line 8 i am using <App />

Comment: btw, are you using webpack 1 or 2?

Comment: @KornholioBeavis i am using webpack 2.2.1

Comment: @KornholioBeavis Thanks for providing the solution but it still giving me same error.

Comment: After paste above code i am getting and error "
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: \index.js Unexpected token (7:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| ReactDOM.render((
|    <App />
| ), document.getElementById('root'));
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap 6298272…:708)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 6298272…:659)
    at bootstrap 6298272…:708
    at bootstrap 6298272…:708"